# Viable library to use HTML with Swing

Tags: java, html, swing

What libraries we can use nowadays to embed HTML with Java Swing. I mean for production ready code. I know there were some lubearies in the past but are there viable options for HTML5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSSBox and SwingBox are still being updated and maintained, and I've used them successfuly in side projects. You can find them here:
[SwingBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox/)
[CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/)

Maybe you can try JavaFX?

Comment: just for further informations : swing can display fx view quite easily and the WebView (from jfx) provide a fully fonctionnal webbrowser (js execution, html/css, etc this is actually the best solution for java 8 or above users.